# Обрезать выводимый текст

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Как в цикле можно обрезать выводимый текст до 10 слов и убрать вывод html, PHP тегов. Вывод контента идёт из таблицы mySQL.

```
     $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM seo_tools WHERE id=".$tool['id'];
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $strSQL);

     $result = mysql_fetch_array($rs);*/

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row['about_tool']; 
     }
```

В придачу в начале контента ещё выводится SELECT * FROM seo_tools WHERE id. strip_tags пробовал, не помогает. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '<b>12345678901234567890</b>';

echo substr(strip_tags($str), 0, 10);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось